# How to change True value into green check in the Django admin ListView

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-admin, admin

models.py

```
class Example(models.Model):
    sort = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, blank=False, null=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(editable=False)
    online = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300, blank=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, blank=True, unique=True)
    main_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images', blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.title)
        if not self.id:
            self.created = timezone.now()
        self.modified = timezone.now()
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)

    def image_tag(self):
        if self.main_image:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

[image: Image Tag]

As you can see if you have `BooleanField` online - it will change the True or False to Green or Red. How can I achieve - that when my ImageField is empty it would do the same. I have created an `image_tag` method that would return True or False but not sure what to do next - do I need to override the template - is there a way to do it without?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way is to set a `boolean` attribute on the method itself. You should also make sure the method always returns a bool.

```
def image_tag(self):
    return bool(self.main_image)
image_tag.boolean = True
```

(This is documented, but there's no way to link to the exact place: see about halfway through the [`list_display`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.list_display) section.)

Comment: I see nice solution, so how it would recognize True or False? If it is False set it False and if True set it true.

Comment: I don't understand your question. That is what it does.

Comment: That code above is doing only when it is True - I need that code to be showing as well Red cross if it is False, I have updated the question.

Comment: Updated the answer; your method should always return a bool, not None.

Comment: if you are getting value from list_display, you can set decorator above the function and specify parameter
@admin.display(boolean=True)